# Why won't it print this variable?

Tags: python

So I'm doing this thing for math that requires a detailed algorithim. The thing is, it won't actually print the answer, and I don't know why. Essentially, the game that we have to find a strategy to goes like this: We have three cards, each with either an X or an O on the back (so the cards are XX, OO, and XO). We have to guess what is on the back of the card, based on what is on the front of the card. The cards are shuffled each time, but I still figure the odds of getting XX and then XX again are low. So I made this code.

```
#math thing
#if the previous one was XX, don't choose XX next time
#if the previous was OO, don't choose OO next time
#if it was XO or OX, choose either O or X as the back
import random 
starter = input("What's on Front? (starter) ")
back = ""
starterBack = ("X", "O")
starter2 = random.choice(starterBack)
print(starter2)
front = input("What's on Front?")
if starterBack == 'X' and starter == 'X' and front == 'X':
  back = O
  print(back)
if starterBack == "O" and starter =="O" and front == "O":
  back = "X"
  print(back)
if starterBack == "O" and starter == "X" and front == "X":
  back = random.choice("O", "X")
  print(back)
```

But it won't print the 'back' variable. Why?

Comment: I think you don't want to check for `starterBack` but rather `starter2`

Comment: `back = O` and `back = random.choice("O", "X")` are gonna throw some errors.

Comment: You should think about all combinations of values and make sure they are handled in your conditional.

Comment: It helps a lot to `print` the variables you want to check before the `if` statement

Answer (score 2):

```
if starterBack == 'X':
```

`starterBack` is a tuple, so it cannot equal a string. To access individual items in the tuple, use square brackets to index it:

```
starterBack[0]
```

This gives the first item - remember, Python starts counting from zero. Giving you:

```
if (starterBack[0] == 'X'
    and started == 'X'
    and front == 'X'):
```

Comment: Didn’t make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

`starterBack` is `("X", "O")`, so the `if starterBack == 'X' ...` and `if starterBack == 'O' ...` conditions will never be true and `back` will never be printed.  Did you perhaps mean to write `starter2` instead of `starterBack` in your `if` conditions?

Comment: Doesn’t make a difference either way. Still won’t print it.

Answer (score 0):

```
starterBack = ("X", "O")
```

is a tuple and you cannot compare value like this `starterBack == "X"`you need to provide a particular index of value in tuple as `X` is at `0` index write it `starterBack[0] == "X"` and change `back = O` into `back = "O"`. And also Pass `back = random.choice(starterBack)` tuple as argument instead of `back = random.choice("X","O").` 

Try this code.

```
import random 
starter = input("What's on Front? (starter) ")

starterBack = ("X", "O")
starter2 = random.choice(starterBack)
print(starter2)
front = input("What's on Front?")
if starterBack[0] == "X" and starter == "X" and front == "X":
    back = "O"
    print(back)
if starterBack[1] == "O" and starter =="O" and front == "O":
    back = "X"
    print(back)
if starterBack[1] == "O" and starter == "X" and front == "X":
    back = random.choice(starterBack)
    print(back)
```